# tasks.loop Invalid Webhook Token after 15 minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that sends a message every hour in a specific channel. I decided to start the loop with a command.

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
   
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/",help_command=None)
slash = SlashCommand(bot,sync_commands=True)

@tasks.loop(minutes=1,count=20)
    async def loop(ctx: SlashContext):
        await ctx.send("loop")
    
@slash.slash(name="start_loop")
async def _start_loop(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.respond(eat=True)
    loop.start(ctx)
    
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

The command works perfectly when it's not looped, but no matter what interval I set after 15 minutes of looping it throws this error

`discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 50027): Invalid Webhook Token`

What is causing this?

Solution:

Replace `ctx.send()` with `ctx.channel.send()` since the former stops working after 15 minutes

Comment: You may need to regenerate the token before you send the next message. Looks like the token expires in between your loops.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, error only occurs when looped, the token doesn't seem to expire when it's not looped

Comment: Did you try using `ctx.send()` multiple times without the loop? This, https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#ctx-send, might be one of the reasons.

Comment: Thank you `ctx.send()` will stop working after 15 minutes and replacing it with `ctx.channel.send()` fixes the problem perfectly